# Symfony API Platform Filter

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have entity who have attributes column which is `@ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)`
And each entity have multiple keys/values in this attributes column 
`"attributes": {
  "name": "Item 1",
  "slug": "item-1",
  "term": "item-1"
}`

Is it possible to create a filter to search slug or some other key in attributes column?
I know the api platform have `@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"attributes": "ipartial"})` and this kind of filter in url looks like `/api/items.json?attributes[]=item-1`.
If posible to set key via url like: `?attributes[slug]=item-1`
Or there is another way to do it?

Comment: You should make a column name, slug and term.